# jQuery Event Firing on Multiple Meteor Elements

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

So I have a button contained in a Bootstrap popover, with multiple elements having the same popover attached. You can look at my [MeteorPad here](http://meteorpad.com/pad/GnJsRbvhcickGJW3o/Popover%20Test) (click each element for the popover).

Whenever you click the button within the popover, it fires across ALL of the popovers, so in my example you will get 3 alerts. If I add a fourth element I will get 4, etc.

This is likely due to the popover having to use the jQuery .on() for events, since it is dynamically created. This means I have to use Template.*name*.rendered instead of Template.*name*.events in Meteor.

```
Template.postItem.rendered = function() {
 var data = Template.instance().data;
  $(".newNumber").popover({
    html: true,
    title: 'Popover',
    content: function() {
        return $("#popover-content").html();
    }
  }); 
  $(document).on('click','#mysubmit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    alert('Hey');
  });
}
```

Is there any way to bind the jQuery .on() to the specific element in Meteor, so that I don't have all my elements firing? If I build this example out statically, everything works just fine, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: FYI rendered function was depurated on the Meteor 1.0.4.2 version, instead use  `Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function () {
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not actually 100% certain why this is happening, but I *believe* what's going on is that you're running the popover function on all of the `.newNumber` elements *each time* you render a post Item.  I think you want to do it only once.

There's a number of ways around this, but in your case the quickest and easiest is going to be to run it only on the instances of `.newNumber` in the template that just rendered.  This can be accomplished by using the [`template.$` selector](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_$), which only selects elements that are members of the given template instance, like so:

```
Template.postItem.rendered = function() {
  var data = Template.instance().data;
    Template.instance().$(".newNumber").popover({
        html: true,
        title: 'Popover',
        content: function() {
            return $("#popover-content").html();
        }
    });
```

}

You can check that fix out in [this Meteorpad.](http://meteorpad.com/pad/FJuiWQRnKhgXZQs8C/Copy%20of%20Popover%20Test)

Comment: Hmm, I see what you are saying, but I can't seem to get the Meteorpad to work. Is it running fine on your end?

Comment: @bluearch117 It looks like I was wrong about the render order.  I've edited my answer; let  me know if that (new) MeteorPad doesn't work for you.

Comment: It works! That makes sense to use the template.$ selector for specific instances.